# SQL Union with COUNT() Function not returning expected results

Tags: sql, count, union, lync

I am trying to return all MSFT Lync Users who have used voice conferencing and the number of times they used it. I have to use the UNION because the table has User1 and User2 who both participated in the conference which I want in one column.

Here is the SQL:

```
SELECT U.UserUri,
       COUNT(U.UserUri) AS COUNT
FROM   SessionDetails AS S
       INNER JOIN Users U
         ON S.User1Id = U.UserId
WHERE  MediaTypes = 48
GROUP  BY U.UserUri
UNION
SELECT U.UserUri,
       COUNT(U.UserUri) AS COUNT
FROM   SessionDetails AS S
       INNER JOIN Users U
         ON S.User2Id = U.UserId
WHERE  MediaTypes = 48
GROUP  BY U.UserUri
```

The returned results have anyone who participated in more than one conference appearing in the list twice, with two count totals. Actually, after typing this out it must be grouping by User1Id and User2ID. If a person had 9 conversations but iniated only 6 of them they would be User1 6 times and User2 3 times, creating the two different groupings.

Now I know why, but any ideas how to return no duplicate UserUri? Any help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do the aggregate after the UNION?

```
SELECT
    T.UserUri, COUNT(*)
FROM
    (
    SELECT U.UserUri
    FROM   SessionDetails AS S
           INNER JOIN Users U
             ON S.User1Id = U.UserId
    WHERE  MediaTypes = 48
    UNION ALL
    SELECT U.UserUri
    FROM   SessionDetails AS S
           INNER JOIN Users U
             ON S.User2Id = U.UserId
    WHERE  MediaTypes = 48
    ) T
GROUP BY 
   T.UserUri
```

Edit: fixed aliases, added ALL to UNION

Comment: Hmm seems like a good idea but it is giving me the error: "Invalid column name 'U'". Seems like it doesn't like the U. in the select statement

Comment: Actually it does not like the T.U. in the first select statement

Comment: This solution does not work because if you aggregate after the union it is only the list of UserUri and the count for each is 1.

Comment: Please edit the answer to be UNION ALL. Using UNION ALL returns all the data instead of just the UserUri's and gives the correct results. Thanks for your help!